# Need help in understanding recursion function calls

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test = 3;
        printFun(test);
    }

    static void printFun(int test) {
        if (test < 1) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d ", test);

            // recursive call
            printFun(test - 1);

            System.out.printf("%d ", test);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is coming as below

> 3 2 1 1 2 3

May anyone help me to understand how this output is coming.

As per my understanding, only 3 2 1 should print, please help me to understand for extra 1 2 3 in the output.

Comment: take a sheet of paper and write the value of `test` on **each** call to printf (I trully emphasize on the **each** word)

Comment: What would it print if you replaced the recursive call with another thing, like `System.out.println("something");`?

Comment: There are two `printf` call on each recursion level and thus you see each number printed twice.

Comment: There are two `printf`s for each number, 3, 2 and 1.

Comment: You can debug each step and check the value of `test` throughout execution. IDE like eclipse, intellij, netbeans etc. can be used for ease of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value twice, before calling the recursive method and afterwards.
Remove the second `System.out.printf("%d ", test);` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The print statement after the printFun() function will be pushed to a stack each time. So, when the loop is finished all the print statements will execute in reverse order. To make the output as 3 2 1, you should remove the print statement after the printFun() method.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below function calls for input 3:

```
printFun(3)-> { print 3, call printFun(2) , print 3, return } 
printFun(2)-> { print 2, call printFun(1) , print 2, return } 
printFun(1)-> { print 1, call printFun(0) , print 1, return } 
printFun(0)-> { return }
```

Imagine, initially calls will go up to down by recursive calls then down to up to return back. So, it will print 3,2,1 then 1,2,3